# Multicolumn Table height

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have a height issue. I'm working with this table. - [enter link description here](http://www.i-kandi.com/Advancedcrystaltest.asp)

I'm trying to get the table to shrink in height. Its way to high length wise. 
If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it. Do you see where the crystal image is? I want that row to be lowered in height. I've tried everything to get it to work, but I cant figure it out.

It needs work. Centering text etc. 
There are ASP.NET sessions being included within the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text-inputs all the way on the right are forcing the cells on the left to expand to their height. The only way to make the other cells "shorter" is to reduce the number of text-inputs on the right (or to make each of them smaller with CSS).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to show the crytal in the middle of the cell, then use the below style for the text.

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your CSS. I have only found one solution to your problem i-e if you reduce the font-size you save lot of heigh in your table.

```
#main_table td
{
   font-size:9px;
}
```